# How do I convert Time(7) to .NET Ticks?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table with some columns of time(7) type.

I now need to convert those columns from time(7) to Ticks as a BIGINT (from .NET), because mssql doesn't support time more than 24 hours.

How do I update those time(7) columns that already exist on the database to now represent the time in ticks using SQL?

For example, if I have in the database a columns with **"07:00"** stored, that would be something like **2384623897129873** as a BIGINT. I want to know how to do this conversion.

Comment: what do you mean @Larnu?. For example, if I have in the database a columns with "07:00" stored, that would be something like 2384623897129873 as a BIGINT. I want to know how do this conversion.

Comment: Misunderstood the statement, sorry.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a datetime instead. Getting a number of ticks equal to more than 24 hours from a time only makes no sense.

Comment: `2384623897129873` is [some date in 8AD](http://tickstodatetime.com). How do you arrive at that?

Comment: @MartinSmith, I just hit my face on the keyboard. Sorry, this was just an example. But the number is similar to that :P

Comment: Do you really need 100ns accuracy? If not, what accuracy do you need?

Comment: `Sorry, this was just an example.` Please update your question with the **exact** result you are looking for. Without that, there is no way for us to compare or evaluate different answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

As this document says:

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.timespan.ticks?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_TimeSpan_Ticks

> There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond

So I converted the Time(7) to milliseconds and then I multiplied by 10.000:

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, 0, MyCurrentDuration)) * 10000 as Ticks from CalculationResult
```

Comment: I'm guessing you want to store values that represents a duration, and in c# translated to a `TimeSpan` (that is perfectly capable of storing values longer than 24 hours) - but as I wrote in my comment to the question, 100ns is *very* accurate you might just want to store the number of seconds and in c# create an instance of `TimeSpan` using the static method `FromSeconds()` - might be even that a minutes resolution will be fine... Just some food for thought.

Comment: I think it's better to use the contructor the accepts "Ticks". TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(782163872163)

Answer (score 1):

As per [the doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_Ticks) the number of ticks in a datetime starts from a specific starting point - 1st Jan 0001. This means that if you want to store ticks as an offset into an arbitrary length day you will need to subtract the number of ticks at the start of that day from the DateTime.Now.Ticks.

As you are keeping time in a cycle that isn't 24 hours make sure you still keep a date with the tick offset - otherwise you won't know if `900,000,000,000` is 25 hours offset from Day 1 or 1 hour offset from Day 2.